# "Error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener" When TNS is declared and using Kerberos

Tags: oracle, node-oracledb

I have a linux service that uses Oracle DB and authenticates using Kerberos. This works fine locally but when I deploy to our Cloud Foundry PAAS I get...

> 2020-05-11T13:49:28.128-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

My `SQLnet.ora` looks like this...

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE = oracle
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (KERBEROS5)
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME =  ${KRB5CCNAME}
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF = ${KRB5_CONFIG}
sqlnet.kerberos5_conf_mit=true
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=SUPPORT
```

And when I run this it prints properly...

```
const x = child.execSync("cat /.../tns/sqlnet.ora", {stdio: 'inherit'})
```

So everything looks right but it still can't find the TNS entry. What is going on and how can I debug it?

I double checked my firewall configuration and it looks like the IP for the DB is clear so I don't think it is a network issue.

Comment: 'No listener' suggests there is not a listener process listening on the expected IP address and port; not that it can't find an entry - presumably you mean an entry in `tnsnames.ora` not `sqlnert.ora`... Are you sure the address and port for the entry you're looking up are correct (including names resolving as expected), and that the listener is actually up? What do you see if you telnet to that address/port instead?

Comment: I can connect to the same TNS connection from my local P.C. (using SQLDeveloper but still using Kerberos) and I tried to set the firewall to allow that IP so I think it should be.

Comment: Also the actual connection string is in a file called tnsnames.ora. The config is in the sqlnet file.

Comment: Test with SQL*Plus or use 'thick-JDBC' connections in SQL Developer.  This lets you compare apples-with-apples.  SQLDev's default underlying libraries are a completely different stack to node-oracledb's

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use tnsping or trcroute utilities to test your connection to the database? It should help you identify the problem.

Comment: I have not can you post some examples?